# Task.When all completes before all tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am downloading some files using async Tasks and using Task.WhenAll completion to detect all files have been downloaded. However WhenAll is completed before all files downloaded.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DownloadFilesTasksAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task DownloadFilesTasksAsync()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach(var blobName in blobNames)
        {
            Task blobDownloadTask = new Task(
                async () =>
                {
                     await new AzureStorageProvider().DownloadFileFromBlob(WebUtility.UrlDecode(blobName));
                     Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {blobName}");                        
                }
            );

            blobDownloadTask.Start();
            tasks.Add(blobDownloadTask);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("After When all");
    }
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O22NZ.png)

Comment: Curious why not using `Task.Run` instead of `new Task`?

Comment: In fact, using `Task.Run` would solve this. The issue is that `Task` doesn't have a ctor which takes a `Func<Task>`, only `Action`. So that `async () ...` gets turned into an `async void` method, and the `Task` completes as soon as `DownloadFileFromBlob` has finished being called, not when that `await` completes. `Task.Run` has an overload which takes a `Func<Task>`. That said, you probably don't need `Task.Run` at all -- call `DownloadFileFromBlob` synchronously, and add the `Task` that's returned to `tasks`

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for your clear explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor#System_Threading_Tasks_Task__ctor_System_Action_) constructor, which accepts an `Action` instead of a `Func<Task>` as the argument. Use [`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) instead if you really want to run on the threadpool. It accepts a `Func<Task>` and properly awaits the function's completion rather than executing in a fire-and-forget fashion like your constructor is currently doing.

Also, try to avoid calling `.GetResult()`, which can potentially cause deadlocks. Instead write your main function like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    await DownloadFilesTasksAsync();
}
```

Comment: `async Task Main`, surely?

Comment: suggesting `async void` is also bad. If they are using more recent version of c# they can use `async Task Main`

Comment: @canton7 does it make a difference? You can't call main.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes it does. `async void Main` will exit when the first `await` is hit, and your console application will terminate there and then. With `async Task Main`, the compiler knows that it has to insert code to wait for that `Task` to complete before the console application can terminate

Comment: @canton7 thank you, I wasn't aware of that. That definitely makes a difference.

Comment: @canton7 does that mean a winforms application can also potentially terminate in the middle of a pending UI event handler since it must be declared as `async void`?

Comment: @canton7 the `static async Task Main(string[] args)` is a [valid Main signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) (starting with C# 7.1). It actually translates to code [very similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) to OP's code, with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: No, Winforms applications don't have a static Main method in the same way, where the application terminates when Main returns.

Comment: @Theodor I know, yes